# Можно ли подать другой источник звука на вход в метод, вместо микрофона?

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder, android-audio-record

Есть класс, позволяющий записывать звук (в данный момент с микрофона телефона) и далее сохранять на карту памяти файл.

Нужно вместо источника звука (MIC - микрофон) записывать звук, который играет через динамик, или другими словами: (приложение воспроизводит аудио, хотел записывать это аудио.).

То есть источником должно быть это аудио, которое играет в телефоне, а не через микрофон. Возможно ли такое?

Фрагмент кода, где на вход подается как раз микрофон:

```
    public void recordAudio(View v) {
    AndroidAudioRecorder.with(this)
            // Required
            .setFilePath(AUDIO_FILE_PATH)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.recorder_bg))
            .setRequestCode(REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO)

            // Optional
            .setSource(AudioSource.MIC) //ЗДЕСЬ ВОЗМОЖНО ДРУГОЙ ИСТОЧНИК ЗВУКА ПОДАТЬ? А ИМЕННО АУДИО, КОТОРОЕ ИГРАЕТ НА УСТРОЙСТВЕ.
            .setChannel(STEREO)
            .setSampleRate(HZ_48000)
            .setAutoStart(false)
            .setKeepDisplayOn(true)

            // Start recording
            .record();
}
```